# CSS image keep ratio when in mobile view

Tags: css, image, mobile, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I have a project where I need to display a image in a website. This image is shown on the background.
But when I try to fit this image for a mobile view the image gets a distorted ratio. I don't mind if the image is zoomed in when in mobile view so that the dimensions are still in tact.

```
<div class="relative h-screen" id="about">
...
    <img
        src="@/assets/img/about/background.png"
        alt="background"
        class="absolute top-0 right-0 z-0 h-screen"
    />
...
</div>
```

This is how the image is shown in a normal desktop view. Te image has a absolute position relative to it's parent div. It has been anchored to the top and right. This is because of the gradient coming from the left.
[image]

This is how the image is being displayed in mobile view. The image is being distorted.
[image]

Comment: take a look at ob-ject-fit and object-position : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

Answer (score 0):

You can try expanding the width and height of your image to fill out the viewport, and then using the `object-fit` property set to `cover` to resize the image and maintaining it's aspect ratio. This will work since the image you're using as a background is a *replaced element*:

```
img.absolute {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* optionally, you can try adjusting the alignment of the image with obejct-position */
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

You can read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit to have a better understanding when it comes to resizing replaced elements.